# $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) f(2021x+2022) \leq 2021x \leq f(2021x)+2022$ detemine the function $f$

Tags: functions, contest-math

$f$ is a function defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$ as follows :
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) f(2021x+2022) \leq 2021x \leq f(2021x)+2022$$
the question is to determine the function $f$ :
I know the solution is $f(x)=x-2021$
what I did, was substitute the $X=2021x$
this is what I got as a result :
$$ f(X+2022) \leq X \leq f(X)+2022$$
then :
$$X-2021 \leq f(X)$$
what I need now is to prove that :

$$f(X) \leq X-2021$$
if there is any other method tell me please.

Answer (score 5):

From your equation
$$f(X+2022) \leq X \leq f(X)+2022$$

From first inequality
$$f(X+2022) \leq X$$

replace $X$ with $X-2022$

So, $f(X)\leq X - 2022$

And from second inequality,
$$X \leq f(X)+2022$$
So, $f(X)\geq X-2022$

So from both above $f(X) = X-2022$

Comment: Short, sweet, yet very clear!